# How to collimate the LASER light using an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, laser

The He-Ne laser beam is passed through electric field plates. What is the mechanism occururing there and the principle of LASER light interacting with electric field?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Light doesn't interact with electric fields, so there's no way to do what you're proposing.

Comment: @Daniel Not right. The frequency of light oscillations and the Hugh velocity c prevent light from being affected by common electric fields. But half wave plates are a good example for the influence of electric fields on molecular level.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - what's an "electric field plate"? There are ways to modulate light by letting an electric field act on the material it passes through, but it's really the field interacting with the material, which then interacts with the light.

Comment: Was the question about the Faraday Effect?

Answer (score 0):

Electric fields can alter the refractive index (and other properties) of materials through which the laser beam passes. For example, the [Pockel's Cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pockels_effect)

Electric fields of the intensity we normally encounter on earth cannot alter vacuum properties significantly.